# Iterating through a nested JSON array and changing the value of a property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, client-side

I have the following JSON object

```
{
    "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
        "nodeDataArray": [{
        "key": "CTR:2",
            "type": "Controller",
            "devicename": "ACU-1K",
            "deviceid": "2",
            "imageUrl": "http://localhost:52233/Images/ComputerSpeaker_32.png",
            "loc": "280 112"
    }, {
        "key": "CTR:1",
            "type": "Controller",
            "devicename": "C302-1",
            "deviceid": "1",
            "imageUrl": "http://localhost:52233/Images/ComputerSpeaker_32.png",
            "loc": "477 92"
    }, {
        "key": "RDR:25",
            "type": "Reader",
            "devicename": "1K-1-RDR01",
            "deviceid": "25",
            "imageUrl": "http://localhost:52233/Images/Plugin_32.png",
            "loc": "592 41"
    }],
        "linkDataArray": []
}
```

I would like to loop through nodeDataArray, and change the value of imageUrl for each item within nodeDataArray

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$.each(jsonCoordinates, function(key, value) {
    var nodeData = value.nodeDataArray;
    $.each(nodeData, function(k, v) {
        v.imageUrl = "default";
    });

});
```

How should it be?

`jsonCoordinates` contains the whole chunk of JSON above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need nested `$.each` methods, iterate through the `nodeDataArray` directly.

```
$.each(jsonCoordinates.nodeDataArray, function(index, value) {
    value.imageUrl = "default";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSzYM/

<sub>A suggestion: always use `console.log()` for debugging your code, specially for iterating through nested objects and arrays.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Since your jsonCoordinates is not an array, when you do the each it doesn't execute. I think your code would work if you wrap it around [];

http://jsfiddle.net/Xu9gH/1/

```
var Data = {"class":"go.GraphLinksModel","nodeDataArray":[{"key":"CTR:2","type":"Controller","devicename":"ACU-1K","deviceid":"2","imageUrl":"http://localhost:52233/Images/ComputerSpeaker_32.png","loc":"280 112"},
{"key":"CTR:1","type":"Controller","devicename":"C302-1","deviceid":"1","imageUrl":"http://localhost:52233/Images/ComputerSpeaker_32.png","loc":"477 92"},
{"key":"RDR:25","type":"Reader","devicename":"1K-1-RDR01","deviceid":"25","imageUrl":"http://localhost:52233/Images/Plugin_32.png","loc":"592 41"}],
"linkDataArray":[]};

$.each(Data.nodeDataArray, function(k, v) {
 v.imageUrl = "default";
});

console.log(Data);
```